# Highlight Multiple Lines in Emacs

Tags: highlighting

I wonder if there is any package which lets me do this:

- Hightlight entire line where point is currently located
- If you move point away, it keeps the that line highlighted
- Multiple lines can be highlighted in similar way
- Clear all highlights with another command

I think this is very useful and I wonder someone would have done it already.

-- A newby EMACS lover.

**Edit**: Adding more explanation
Let's say I have a file with 10 lines, I want to highlight 3rd, 5th and 7th line. What I would like to do is, move point to those lines one by one and execute some command (let's say highlight-this-line), it should keep the past highlighted lines as highlighted until let's say clear-highlight-command is executed which should clear all highlights

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't clear enough. Answer to your first question: not exactly. Let me elaborate. Let's say I have a file with 10 lines, I want to highlight 3rd, 5th and 7th line. What I would like to do is, move point to those lines one by one and execute some command (let's say `highlight-this-line`), it should keep the past highlighted lines as highlighted until let's say `clear-highlight-command` is executed which should clear all highlights.

Comment: Please update your question with that explanation (which is clear). Thx.

Comment: Your second question: Yes, I know `C-SPC` would help but not the way I would like to, that would simply highlight entire text between my last mark and current point location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)).

```el
(defun highlight-this-line ()
  "Highlight the current line."
  (interactive)
  (hlt-highlight-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
```

You can also pass the `FACE` to use as an arg to `hlt-highlight-region`.

Comment: Thanks Drew for super quick reply, I would try this one and see.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks very much.

Comment: Following up on this, I am also looking for the follwoing:
1. changing the background color of highlight
2. having a defun which would clear all highlights in buffer

Would you suggest something? Thanks

Comment: You should ask separate questions for those things. SE is a Q & A site, that intentionally looks for specific questions with specific answers. However: see the Commentary in [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el), where it says (1) you can use any face to highlight or unhighlight, (2) you can use command `hlt-choose-default-face` to choose a face for highlighting, (3) you can alternatively choose a color name instead of a face, and (4) you can also choose a face using command `hlt-next-face`. See also option `hlt-auto-face-backgrounds`. Read the Commentary.

Comment: Thanks very much Drew. I would ask a new question in new post, beginner here as well :)

Comment: The author of that package is YOU! Thank you! 